# Realizar um redirect em Construtor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Como posso fazer um `Response.Redirect()` em um construtor de classe?

```
public class FarmaciaController : Controller{

    public FarmaciaController(){
        if(!userLogin.usuarioTemPermissao("Farmacia"))
         Response.Redirect("~/PortalFarmacia/Home");
    }  

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redirecionamento no construtor pode dar alguns problemas devido ao contexto além de não ser uma boa prática, uma solução é você criar um [atributo customizado pra sua action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410056%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) e sobrescrever o método `OnActionExecuting` para fazer a validação.

```
public class ValidarPermissaoActionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        if (/* verificar se o usuario tem permissão */)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
            {
                controller = "PortalFarmacia",
                action = "Home"
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

E no seu **Controller**

```
public class FarmaciaController : Controller
{
    [ValidarPermissaoAction]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // Essa action só vai ser executada se a validação tiver ok
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Como eu faria para pegar um atributo da Class que está chamando a validação ? (Passar um parâmetro)

Comment: @DanielGregatto Se você quer validar o usuário logado é só pegar do `context`, não? Que atributo exatamente você precisa da classe?

Comment: Estou validando níveis de permissão para os controllers do sistema, quero passar um parametro dizendo o Controller que eu estou e com isso eu consigo validar utilzando meu usuário logado.

Comment: @DanielGregatto Você consegue pegar o nome do Controller dessa forma `filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName`

Comment: Era isso que eu precisava Maicon, obrigado! Abraço!